# formControlName directive and FormArray issue

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive

I am learning an Angular book and I'm stuck on a reactive form example. I've copied one to one code from the book and it does not work at all. I've checked many docs and I found one different way to solve the problem, but still don't understand what I'm doing wrong with this concrete example. Can anyone help? Thanks!

**Component's code**:

```
 heroDetails = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    realName: new FormControl(''),
    biometricData: new FormGroup({
      age: new FormControl(''),
      eyes: new FormControl(''),
      hair: new FormControl('')
    }),
    powers: new FormArray([])
    });

  get powers(): FormArray {
    return this.heroDetails.controls.powers as FormArray;
  }
  
  addPower() {
    this.powers.push(new FormControl(''));
  }
```

**Template markup**:

```
<form [formGroup]="heroDetails">
    <button (click)="addPower()">Add power</button>
    <div *ngFor="let power of powers.controls; index as i">
        <label>
        Power:
        <input type="text" [formControlName]="i">
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I launch the app and press "Add power" button I get the following error in browser's console:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: '0'
```

**The workaround I found**:

```
<form [formGroup]="heroDetails">
    <button (click)="addPower()">Add power</button>
    <div *ngFor="let power of powers.controls; index as i">
        <label>
        Power:
        <input type="text" [formControl]="powers.controls[i]">
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `i` in the template becomes 0 because it's an index, not the formGroup key. What the problem to use the second example?

Comment: since you are iterating powers.control values as power instead of using [formControl] ="powers.controls[i]" you can directly use [formControl] ="power".

Comment: @Ярослав, formGroup key remain the same - "powers", it is not clear what name has new FormControl when I add it to the powers FormArray. I'm curious why the example from the book is not working and it is not first time I finding similar way of doing, but it is not working and I wonder why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `formArrayName` in your controls loop.

```
<form [formGroup]="heroDetails">
    <button (click)="addPower()">Add power</button>
    <div formArrayName="powers" *ngFor="let power of powers.controls; index as i">
        <label>
        Power:
        <input type="text" [formControlName]="i">
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

working `stackblitz` example: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-angular-ojruc3?file=src/app/app.component.html**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've added formArrayName and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Add a new form control in your form group like this:

```
heroDetails.addControl('controlName', new FormControl());
```

Comment: But I'm adding a FormControl not to the FormGroup but to the FormArray, moreover I'm adding it dynamically and I don't know what the name of added FormControl will be...